# nativescript create 2 apps instead of 1

Tags: javascript, android, nativescript, tns

So when i run: `../../latest-cli/nativescript-cli/bin/tns livesync android --watch`

the app create 2 icons( 2 apps ).
The first one works, the second one gives error( `cannot load module app/main.js` ).

What could couse this ? I need the working one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure in your AndroidManifest.xml that you don't have two

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

If thats the case you can change one of them to

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Its built by gradle, so there shouldn't be foult in that.

Comment: Voted up because you can't summarily dismiss the suggestion from Misha "because the manifest is generated by gradle".  

3rd party plugins can modify the contents that get merged into the final AndroidManifest.xml. 

A custom AndroidManifest may be in your project as well.

Your question is also missing version information regarding the nativescript tooling you are using.  Your command to start the environment in which this problem is occurring indicates a non-standard scenario, one in which more information would be nice to have.

Comment: Indeed custom AndroidManifest is present in each NativeScript app in app/App_Resources/Android folder